# Python local variables in methods

Tags: python, oop, python-3.x

I am learning Python 3 and I have very fundamental question regarding object oriented programming in Python. Here is my code.

```
class pet:
    number_of_legs = 0
    def count_legs(self):
        print("I have %s legs" %dog.number_of_legs)

dog = pet()
dog.number_of_legs = 4
dog.count_legs()
```

This code prints:

```
I have 4 legs
```

Why count_legs method does not give error like "Unknown variable dog in print."
The variable dog exist outside the class.

How this code is working ? What is motivation behind such behavior ?

Comment: _"The variable dog exist outside the class"_. Yep, and that's why the method doesn't give an error. There's no rule that says "methods in classes can't see variables outside the class".

Answer (score 10):

`dog` is looked up as a global *at runtime*; had you named your variable differently the code *would* have thrown an error:

```
>>> class pet:
...     number_of_legs = 0
...     def count_legs(self):
...         print("I have %s legs" %dog.number_of_legs)
... 
>>> cat = pet()
>>> cat.number_of_legs = 4
>>> cat.count_legs()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in count_legs
NameError: name 'dog' is not defined
>>> dog = cat
>>> cat.count_legs()
I have 4 legs
```

This makes it easy to refer to *other* globals in the module that are defined *later*; this *includes* recursive functions:

```
def fib(n):
    if n <= 1: return n
    return fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2)
```

When defining `fib()` there is no global name `fib` *yet*; only when the function object has been created is the global added. If the name had to exist *first* you'd end up with code like:

```
fib = None  # placeholder for global reference

def fib(n):
    if n <= 1: return n
    return fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2)
```

and that is just noise.

Comment: @Martijin: And what is the motivation behind such behavior ? In which condition it is useful ?

Comment: An interesting example to see how python works, but in real life this is of course very bad coding practice, just use `print("I have %s legs" % self.number_of_legs)` to print the variable.

Comment: @vivekratnaparkhi: It's useful because you often need to refer to names outside of the class's scope such as imported modules, builtin functions, or other classes in your module.

Comment: Thanks all for your comments. I was just curious why this is allowed.

Comment: @Gio: sure, but the OP wanted to know *why* it worked.

Comment: @usar: you still need to explain that an error is thrown at runtime, illustrating this is dynamic.